# Python OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory ERROR

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, subprocess, call

I'm having troubles with running OS commands on Linux through python (which i did LOTS of time in the past)

I'm trying to run a simple OS command, using the `subprocess` module:

```
def test_func():
    cmd = 'mkdir /tmp/test_dir'
    res = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

And I'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/fiverr_dev/fiverr-bi/apps/apis/api_acq_bing_reports.py", line 92, in <module>
    acquisition_reports.test_func()
  File "/Volumes/fiverr_dev/fiverr-bi/apps/etls/acquisition_reports.py", line 177, in test_func
    res = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This suddenly started to happen. I've been dealing with python `venv`s, maybe it somehow effected the issue.

The error occurs for ANY command I'm trying to run on linux...
It seems like a pretty generic problem.

Anyone has an idea what has gotten wrong ?

Comment: Why doesn't the traceback match your code?

Comment: I tried couple of versions. both ```subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()```
AND
```subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))```
[ I fixed the code in the main thread ]

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error as python is attempting to the following underneath.

```
(ins)-> cmd='mkdir /tmp/hello'
(ins)-> "$cmd"
-bash: mkdir /tmp/hello: No such file or directory
```

Use shlex.split(cmd) in the python

```
In [13]: cmd = 'mkdir /tmp/hello'

In [14]: args = shlex.split(cmd)

In [15]: subprocess.Popen(args)
Out[15]: <subprocess.Popen at 0x10e1f74e0>
```